# Using combobox like an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I have problems about my project. But I cannot find answer properly. I use so many comboboxes and textboxes. I have this function:

```
    private void combo1add(string options, int combono)
    { 
        openconnection();  //Function that open mysql connection
        if (combono==1) comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        if (combono==6) comboBox6.Items.Clear();
        if (combono == 7) comboBox7.Items.Clear();
        string query = "select * from material";
        if (options == "Non Ceramic")
        {
            query = "select * from material where type='metal'";
        }
        command = new MySqlCommand(command, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = komut.ExecuteReader();
        if (combono == 1)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(oku["materialno"].ToString());
            }
        }
        if (combono == 6)
        {
            while (oku.Read())
            {
                comboBox6.Items.Add(oku["materialno"].ToString());
            }
        }
        if (combono == 7)
        {
            while (oku.Read())
            {
                comboBox7.Items.Add(oku["materialno"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this code in my project. But I have over 20 combobox and I want to use it like a array in example: I want also use textbox like an array but when i try its takes always error.

```
while (oku.Read())
{
    comboBox[i].Items.Add(oku["materialno"].ToString());
}
```

but I cannot success in my research. I have new at c#. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/) to see how you can improve your post to get more answers.

Comment: add the comboboxes into an array, or list, or dictionary, and you can access each combobox by an index or a key.

Comment: thanks nvoigt I will keep it in mind. Sorry its my first question I will learn the rules in time. Kennyzx you give an idea to what I wanna do but the question is how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code takes all the combo boxes from your form into an array:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ComboBox[] cbs;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbs = getControls<ComboBox>(this).ToArray();
        foreach (var cb in cbs) MessageBox.Show(cb.Name);
    }

    IEnumerable<T> getControls<T>(Control top) where T : Control
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        foreach (Control c in top.Controls) {
            if (c is T)
            {
                result.Add((T)c);
            }
            result.AddRange(getControls<T>(c));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

getControls procedure can be used to collect controls of any type, e.g. Button

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! İt's worked but it get reverse array like combobox1, combobox2, combobox3 = cb[0]=combobox3, cb[1]=combobox2, cb[2]=combobox1. any way to correct this? It's useful like this but I have to make convertion.

Comment: to reverse order of elements in any collection, use Reverse() extension method:

getControls<ComboBox>(this).Reverse().ToArray()